# How to configure ingress rule for redirecting to IP based url rather than service name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, forwarding

i have ingress file where i am forwarding request to pods using service name but i have a scenario where few requests with path /abc* needs to be forwarded to ip based url say http://10.10.1.1:8080/. How to do this case using ingress in Kubernetes and i am using AWS EKS as my kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Service` using [Endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) for that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.10.1.1
    ports:
      - port: 8080
```